# Configuring Azure Container Service with Docker Swarm for SSL

Tags: ssl, azure, docker-swarm

I have an Azure Container Service instance running Docker Swarm which contains instances of a single web application written in NodeJS.

I now want to ensure all traffic comes to the website via HTTPS.  I cannot find any documentation on how to set up certificates and domain names for Azure Container Service.  Would i be right in assuming that the best practice here is to stand an NGINX container in front of the web app containers, and configure the certificate & domain name there?

The Azure Container Service has an azure load balancer in front of the swarm, but there is nothing that suggests how to configure an SSL certificate for it.

It is not obvious what the best approach is, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am looking for the same question, will this help
http://technolo-g.com/generate-ssl-for-docker-swarm/